# Angular6 form with action and POST call to SERVLET not working

Tags: angular, servlets, angular6, http-post, forms

I am trying to make a request to a servlet in an html form as shown in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm)

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" ngNoForm  action="/hub/rpt/run" target="_blank"  method="POST" > 
    <div *ngFor="let parameter of reportParams" class="form-row">
      <reporting-form-parameter [parameter]="parameter" [form]="form"></reporting-form-parameter>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
      <button type="reset" (click)="form.reset()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The servlet is as follows below

```
Component(
        service = Servlet.class,
        scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE,
        property = {
                "alias=/hub/rpt/run",
                "servlet-name=ReportServlet"
        })
```

I am trying to submit the form data to the servlet, but the Http post call is not being called( nothing in the network ).

There are very few resources on **angular2+ integration with a servlet with form data** ( not the rest api )

Am I missing something regarding the integration?

Note: I am able to hit the servlet through *rest api*

Comment: We need to see how you implement the http.post call in the Angular side, but this smells like you haven't subscribed to it.

Comment: I am trying ( https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm ) this way. There is no concept of subscription here.